# How to traverse a list in 'if loop'

Tags: python-3.x, loops, if-statement

I have trying to traverse the value of **i** as in the list corpus but everytime it doesnt satisfy the if condition, it exits the loop.

```
for word in vocab:
    print(word)
        #   print("in loop")
    if word in corpus[i]:
        print(corpus[i])
        count = count + 1
        print(i,count)
    else :
        i = i+1
```

Here i am trying to increase the value of i by 1 without the loop exiting the **if loop**  and starting with the **for loop**. Please help.

Comment: Just a note: there's no such thing as an "if loop". You have a conditional statement (the `if`) inside of a `for`-loop.

Comment: Also, please show `vocab` and note what output you're expecting.

Comment: Please provide sample input, expected output and current output. It looks to me like the issue is that you only increment i if the condition isn't met which means you'll get stuck.

Comment: I don't understand what you want exactly...